# read: Illegal option -d

Tags: bash

Here is the offending part of my script:

```
read -d '' TEXT <<'EOF'
Some Multiline
text that
I would like
in 
a 
var
EOF

echo "$TEXT" > ~/some/file.txt
```

and the error:

```
read: 175: Illegal option -d
```

I use this read -d all over the place and it works fine. Not sure why its not happy now. I'm running the script on Ubuntu 10.10

Fixes? Workarounds?

Comment: I assume you are using the `bash` shell on Ubuntu.  If so, does `help read` show the `-d` option?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you run `sh` and then try that command, you get:

```
read: 1: Illegal option -d
```

If you do it while still in `bash`, it works fine.

I therefore deduce that your script is *not* running under `bash`.

Make sure that your script begins with the line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

(or equivalent) so that the correct shell is running the script.

Alternatively, if you cannot do that (because the script is not a `bash` one), just be aware that `-d` is a `bash` feature and may not be available in other shells. In that case, you will need to find another way.

Comment: HA! So minor, so easy to miss. Based on your answer I needed to `chmod 775 thefile.sh; ./thefile.sh` because `sh thefile.sh` was the culprit. Also, I'm using the shebang `#!/bin/bash` with no probs. +1

Answer (score 5):

The `-d` option to `read` is a feature unique to bash, not part of the POSIX standard (which only specifies `-r` and `-p` options to `read`). When you run your script with `sh` on Ubuntu, it's getting run with dash, which is a POSIX shell, and not bash. If you want the script to run under bash then you should run it with bash, or give it a `#!/bin/bash` shebang. Otherwise, it should be expected to run under any POSIX sh.