# How do I extract everything in a file after the first null character from shell

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file that looks like this: `some ascii stuff\0some more ascii stuff\0and a little more ascii stuff\0`.

I want to extract everything after the first `\0`.  So my output after this process would be `some more ascii stuff\0and a little more ascii stuff\0`

How would I go about doing this?  This is done within initramfs so my access to commands is somewhat limited.  I do have `cut`, `grep`, and `awk` which I've been trying to get work, but I'm just not having any luck.

This utils are mostly busybox and `sh` for the shell

Comment: An actual null byte

Comment: One rather pertinent question -- *which shell?* If this is dash, f/e, I'd want to test there distinctly. If it's one of busybox's even-more-minimal shells, that makes the need for environment-specific testing more acute.

Comment: If you don't have `read -d`, there are certainly other tricks available (do you have `xargs -0`?), but they get ugly.

Comment: no xargs, but I may be able to pull that in.  I'm working on getting the init script to run under bash instead of sh now.

Comment: ...you have a script that works with sh but not bash? I'm curious! (The only incompatibilities bash has with the POSIX spec that come to mind revolve around default `echo` behavior, and I wouldn't usually expect them to cause outright breakage).

Comment: This is the SO question that told me about the difference.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/5098661/275354

Comment: Well, yes, practices and scripts that work in bash but not sh are easy to come by. I thought you said there were other changes you need to make for the existing written-for-`sh` code to work with bash; for that to happen (when your `sh` is properly POSIX-compliant and you aren't relying on non-POSIX extensions) requires a place where bash is breaking the spec, and outside `echo -e`, those are fairly rare.

Comment: Ohh, this is in the init script which initramfs seems to use sh by default.  I got your answer working by explicitly use shell for the command though.  And thanks for the help @CharlesDuffy I'm a bit out of my wheelhouse with this stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easily done, with nothing but shell builtins (well, `cat` isn't a builtin, but you can substitute it with the actual intended consumer of your stream):

```
{ IFS= read -r -d '' _; cat; } <yourfile
```

`read -d ''` reads everything, one byte at a time, up to the first NUL on stdin. What's left on that stream, thus, is all the content *after* that NUL.

---

You can test it as follows:

```
printf '%s\0' one two three | { IFS= read -r -d '' _; hexdump -C; }
```

...which properly emits:

```
00000000  74 77 6f 00 74 68 72 65  65 00                    |two.three.|
0000000a
```

Comment: I think this will work!  It was at first complaining that -d wasn't a valid option. But after seeing this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/5098661/275354) I switched to using bash it looks like it worked.  Will accept this once I test it out a little more.

Comment: I had to do this in bash instead of the default `sh` but I ended up getting this to work.    Thanks!

Comment: They just changed some requirements on me.  Before I open a new question, would this also work for `0x81` as the delimiter instead of `0x00`  I tried removing the `-r` flag and just changing the empty string to `\x81` but that gave me an empty string.

Comment: It would be `IFS= read -r -d $'\x81'` -- the `$''` quoting form is mandatory. Otherwise, `-d` looks only at the first character of its argument, so sees `'\x81'` as referring to the backslash character alone. See also https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings

Answer (score 1):

Using `gnu awk` you can do this:

```
awk -F '\\0' 'NR == 1{sub($1 FS, "")} 1' file
```

```
some more ascii stuffand a little more ascii stuff
```

Verify output with `od -c`:

```
awk -F '\\0' 'NR == 1{sub($1 FS, "")} 1' file | od -c
```

```
0000000   s   o   m   e       m   o   r   e       a   s   c   i   i
0000020   s   t   u   f   f  \0   a   n   d       a       l   i   t   t
0000040   l   e       m   o   r   e       a   s   c   i   i       s   t
0000060   u   f   f  \0  \n
0000065
```

Comment: When I try this as is I get a "The delimiter must be a single character".  If I use -d '' I my output is a bunch of newlines.  The number of newlines equals the number of null chars in the original string.

Comment: Please try my suggested `gnu awk` as an alternative

Comment: I tried, but it replaced my null chars with new lines.

Comment: Strange. Try: `awk -F '\\0' -v OFS='\\0' '{sub($1 FS, "")} 1' file`

Comment: That put new lines in as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you have grep, you most likely also have sed.
This works for me:

```
echo -e "one\000two\000three" | sed 's/[^\o000]*\o000//'
```

Comment: For me, this just outputs the input

Comment: It does definitely work on Fedora 29 which comes with GNU sed 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `perl`

```
perl -n0e 'print unless $.==1'
```

The `-0` sets the record separator to the null byte, and the print prints everything except the first record.

Comment: Unfortunately perl isn't available

Answer (score 0):

Whether this works for you or not will depend on the version of awk you have available at that time ... this works for me w/ GNU awk 4.1.3

```
echo -e 'some ascii stuff\0some more ascii stuff\0and a little more ascii stuff\0'| awk 'BEGIN{RS="\0";ORS="\t"} NR>1{print $0}'
some more ascii stuff   and a little more ascii stuff
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it just outputs an empty string.